# Private String variable not showing in Text Label vba

Tags: excel, vba, properties, userform, caption

I want to pass an argument to a user form. The solution that I tried is to set a home made property of my userform (which name is InformationMissing), setting a private variable.
Here's the code of my UserForm

```
Private msMsg As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox msMsg
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    txtLabel1.Caption = "hello" & msMsg
End Sub

Property Let MyProp(sText As String)
    msMsg = sText
End Property
```

I'm using this Userform from another sub that sets the MyProp property to a String ("aa" in this case):

```
Sub ShowFormProp()

    Dim myForm As InformationMissing
    Set myForm = New InformationMissing

    myForm.MyProp = "aa"
    myForm.Show

End Sub
```

What I want to do here is to have "helloaa" prined in my UserForm but I only get "hello". However, when I click the CommandButton1, I get "aa".
This means that the property has correctly been set but is not passed to txtLabel1.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the `UserForm_Initialize` procedure. My guess is that it executes before you can set `myForm.myProp`.

Comment: in your `CommandButton1_Click` sub the variable name is `msMgs` while in other subs the variable is `msMsg` ..

Comment: @LatifaShi Yes this is a mistake I've noticed, this was fixed but didn't help. Thanks anyway. I think Inarion is right. I'll check and come back to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserForm.Initialize` is not the correct place to put `txtLabel1.Caption = "hello" & msMsg`, if you want the caption to reflect changes to the private string variable. `Initialize` will always be executed before you can access *any* of the form's properties.

In your case a good solution would be to perform the changes you want directly in the property procedure.

```
Property Let MyProp(sText As String)
    msMsg = sText
    ' You can also put the caption change in its own sub, if you want more things to happen when you change it
    txtLabel1.Caption = "hello" & msMsg
End Property
```

---

Edit: And to reflect what @LatifaShi said in the comments to your question: You've got a typo in there. `msMgs` and `msMsg` are not the same variable. Always use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each module to prevent this and and many more problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the asnwer. Indeed I think that Initialize is executed before anything else and then MyProp didn't take the value.

Comment: @Alex955 If my answer solved your problem, would you kindly accept my answer? ([Why should I mark answers as accepted and how to do it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)) Thanks!